# How do i fix my Unity 2D c# OnTriggerEnter2D delay?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

Hello i have some Problems with my Teleport code for my unity 2d game
I'm trying to delay my Teleport for my fade screen but it doesn't work

also i need

```
other.transform.position = teleportTo.position;
```

And not this, is this the part the player isn't teleporting

```
transform.position = teleportTo.position;
```

Full code

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class TeleportTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TriggerType { Enter, Exit };

    //The Transform to teleport to
    [SerializeField] Transform teleportTo;

    //The filter Tag
    [SerializeField] string tag = "Player";

    //Trigger Event to Teleport
    [SerializeField] TriggerType type;


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        Time.timeScale = 0f;

        if (type != TriggerType.Enter)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (tag == string.Empty || other.CompareTag(tag))
        {
            //TP
            StartCoroutine(Wait());

            //all this \/ is not working there is no delay


            /*other.transform.position = teleportTo.position;
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            */
        }

    }
     private IEnumerator Wait()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        transform.position = teleportTo.position;


        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

After setting

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

The

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
```

will **never** finish since [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) depends on the `Time.timeScale`!

You rather want to use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)

```
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
```

which ignores the timescale.

---

For your other issue you can just pass on all required parameters to the Coroutine

```
IEnumerator Wait(Transform targetTransform)
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime (5);

    targetTransform.position = teleportTo.position;

    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

and

```
StartCorouine (Wait(other.transform));
```

---

Also are you sure that

```
Time.timeScale = 0f;
```

should happen **always** even of you return and don't trigger a teleport?

I would rather move this into the coroutine so it is only applied when you know that afterwards you will definitely reset it again.